# In = 3.7V / Out = 5.2V @ 2A Switching Regulator

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm setting up a Step-Up Boost circuit for my main board using the MT3608 CI. It will be powered by a 18650 3.7v battery and need to output 5.2v @ 2A.

Reading the datasheet ( http://prom-electric.ru/media/MT3608.pdf ) of MT3608 I saw that it regulates its output through R1, R2 and the Schottky diode.

I wonder if R1 and R2 are correct and what is the value of my diode to get 5.2v output?

My Schematic:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The formula for setting the output voltage is given on page 6 of the data sheet, the values of R1 and R2 you've chosen will result in a very high voltage. Values of 47k and 6.2k will be closer to getting 5.2v output with a 0.6v reference.

The schottky diode is not part of the voltage regulation, it's required for the basic operation of the converter. Diode selection is also covered on page 6.

You are unlikely to get 2A out of this converter, notwithstanding its headline figure is 2A and the switch current 4A. Read the data sheet in detail, and once you've read the efficiency curves and power dissipation limits, and applied them to your specific operating point, I'm sure you'll agree. Don't forget that an 18650 is not a 3.7v battery, you will probably want to use it down to 3v, 2.7v if you're hardcore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Neil_UK ! But then it's impossible for me to get 2A out? I need more than 1A (almost 2A) to charge a LiPo battery and connect a raspberry PI with display. As for 18650, I got confused. I will use a 3.7V LiPo.

Comment: A '3.7v LiPo' is not a 3.7v battery. You will want to use it down to 3v, 2.7v if you're hardcore. When charged, it's 4.2v, just like the 18650.

Comment: Now I understand about the battery, sorry for the confusion.
What I wanted to do was a DC / DC boost converter on my main board. I have a powerboost 1000 from the adafruit to power my project, however I need it on the same board as my main circuit and not on separate boards.
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000-basic/overview